# testdriven.io: Test-Driven Development with FastAPI and Docker: Error: Exec format error

Tags: docker, heroku, testdriven.io

I'm going through the course Test-Driven Development with FastAPI and Docker from testdriven.io. I am in Part 2 - Deployment.

When I build the docker container, I can run it locally on my machine. However, when I deploy it to Heroku, it crashes when it starts.

Here are the Heroku logs:

```
2022-08-22T17:59:15.529434+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user xxxx@gmail.com
2022-08-22T17:59:15.529434+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (77071f1ecb57) by user xxxx@gmail.com
2022-08-22T17:59:15.997402+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-22T17:59:25.752365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 
`/bin/sh -c gunicorn\ --bind\ 0.0.0.0:\57978\ app.main:app\ -k\ uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`
2022-08-22T17:59:26.831935+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Exec format error
2022-08-22T17:59:26.985717+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2022-08-22T17:59:27.082554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-22T17:59:27.086528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-22T17:59:38.283248+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 
`/bin/sh -c gunicorn\ --bind\ 0.0.0.0:\15987\ app.main:app\ -k\ uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`
2022-08-22T17:59:39.693305+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Exec format error
2022-08-22T17:59:39.862628+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2022-08-22T17:59:40.007558+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I cannot find any documentation on the error message or on `status 126`.

Here is my Dockerfile.prod:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.10.1-slim-buster

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup --system app && adduser --system --group app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV ENVIRONMENT prod
ENV TESTING 0

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install netcat gcc postgresql \
    && apt-get clean

# install python dependancies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install "uvicorn[standard]==0.16.0"

# copy app
COPY . .

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to teh app user
USER app

# run gunicorn
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app.main:app -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

Heroku seems to complain about the last line, but I cannot figure out the issue. I will really appreciate some help.

Comment: The backslashes in the error message are pretty weird. Is your `Dockerfile.prod` UTF-8 encoded? Are you sure this is the `Dockerfile` that's being used?

Comment: One thing `Exec format error` can mean is that you've built an image on an ARM system (like an M1 Mac) but are trying to run it on an Intel system.  Is that potentially something you're doing?